# xticks' labels formatting in Julia Plots

Tags: julia, julia-plots

Assume my Julia code is

```
using Plots

t = -π:1e-4:π
y = sin.(t)
plot(t,y,lw=3,legend=false)
plot!(xticks=([-π/2],["(-\\pi)/2"]))
```

where I **want to show the parenthesis** in the numerator of xticks' label while **keeping its "rational" form**, i.e., I don't want the numerator and the denominator to be inline. The output of the above code looks like this

[image]

One may see that the xticks' label does not include the desired parenthesis.

Here is another code to show the above function:

```
using Plots

t = -π:1e-4:π
y = sin.(t)
plot(t,y,lw=3,color=2,legend=false)
plot!(xticks=([-π/2],["(-π)/2"]))
```

which as it can be seen, the only difference with the former is in the xticks' label (in the former it is `\\pi` while in the latter it is `π`).
Now the picture looks like this:

[image]

which does not show the label in the "rational" form, i.e., both numerator and the denominator are inline which is undesired. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `using LaTeXStrings`:

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings
gr()
t = -π:1e-4:π
y = sin.(t)
plot(t,y,lw=3,legend=false)
plot!(xticks=([-π/2],[L"\frac{(-\pi)}{2}"]))
```

[image]